# Retrieving and decoding amplitude modulated sin

Tags: java, android, audio, signal-processing

For my diploma I need to encode some data in audio, play it via speakers, recive this audio at other Android phone and decode it back. For this case I've choosed an amplitude modulated sin, in java it will look like this:

```
    void genTone(){
    // fill out the array
    for (int i = 0; i < numSamples; ++i) {
        sample[i] = (binareArray.get(i))*Math.sin((2 * Math.PI - .001) * i / (sampleRate/freqOfTone));
    }


    // convert to 16 bit pcm sound array
    // assumes the sample buffer is normalised.
    int idx = 0;
    int ramp = numSamples / 20;

    for (int i = 0; i < ramp; i++) {
        // scale to maximum amplitude
        final short val = (short) ((sample[i] * 32767) * i / ramp);
        // in 16 bit wav PCM, first byte is the low order byte
        generatedSnd[idx++] = (byte) (val & 0x00ff);
        generatedSnd[idx++] = (byte) ((val & 0xff00) >>> 8);
    }

    for (int i = ramp; i < numSamples - ramp; i++) {
        // scale to maximum amplitude
        final short val = (short) ((sample[i] * 32767));
        // in 16 bit wav PCM, first byte is the low order byte
        generatedSnd[idx++] = (byte) (val & 0x00ff);
        generatedSnd[idx++] = (byte) ((val & 0xff00) >>> 8);
    }

    for (int i = numSamples - ramp; i < numSamples; i++) {
        // scale to maximum amplitude
        final short val = (short) ((sample[i] * 32767) * (numSamples - i) / ramp);
        // in 16 bit wav PCM, first byte is the low order byte
        generatedSnd[idx++] = (byte) (val & 0x00ff);
        generatedSnd[idx++] = (byte) ((val & 0xff00) >>> 8);
    }
}
 void playSound(){
        final AudioTrack audioTrack = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
                sampleRate, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO,
                AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, generatedSnd.length,
                AudioTrack.MODE_STATIC);
        audioTrack.write(generatedSnd, 0, generatedSnd.length);
        audioTrack.play();
    }
```

Now data is generating randomly and later translates from Dec to Bin, like this:

```
void genArray(){
    Random random = new Random();
    ArrayList<Integer> randArray = new ArrayList<>();
    binareArray = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i<numSamples; i++) {
        randArray.add(random.nextInt(100));
    }
    for (int i = 0; i<numSamples; i++) {
        String s = Integer.toBinaryString(randArray.get(i));
        for (String q : (s.split(""))) {
            if (q.equals("")){}
            else {
                binareArray.add(Integer.parseInt(q));
            }
        }
    }
    textView.setText(binareArray.toString());

}
```

So now I'm stuck with receiving and decoding data. Can you give me an advice please, how to receivie and decode data effectively? P.S. this is an example of audio, recorded by PC microphone ([LINK](https://soundcloud.com/luvd0prln5py/recorded-data))

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you define a unique start and end sequence. Add those before and after your data. Let the control sequences be for example "START" and "END". So your sent data looks like:

```
STARTyour data you want to sendEND
```

On the Android device you then continuously decode the received audio until you find "START" on the stream. Then you store the decoded content until "END" is on the stream.

What you receive should look like:

```
noisenoisenoiseSTARTyour data you want to sendENDnoisenoisenoise
```

For the start and end sequence you must use squences that cannot appear in your data. If your data can be completely random you must define a block encoding that reserves at least one block to mark control signals. Be "X" the control block mark. You can define BEGIN and END then as "XB" and "XE" by knowing that the block after X is a command.

Your data parts should not be to long and best you send them multiple times. Otherwise you will need some error correction. Then I would recommend to do research on existing transmission protocols and don't implement your own.

Answer (score 0):

binareArray.get(i) seems like it would deliver a different sample for each value of i. You definitely don't want to change sample faster than the frequency of your carrier.
I honestly can't tell what you are doing with the "ramp". It seems like a little synchronization header to determine ranges before and after your data is appropriate, but your data wouldn't be involved in that calculation.

As far as decoding goes, look for peaks in your signal and those should be your data. If you synchronize them with your carrier, this becomes easy. Then you just have to scale by the minimum and maximum values you got from your header and you are done.